# Detect if email is essentially text

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, email-client, heuristics

I'm writing an Outlook Add-in that saves emails for historical purposes. Outlook's MSG format is unfortunately overly-verbose, even when compressed. This causes saved MSG files to be many times the size of their text equivalent. However, saving all messages as text has the obvious pitfalls of lacking attachments, images, and any relevant formatting.

For the majority of emails this isn't an issue, however emails with a certain degree of complex formatting, pictures, attachments, (etc...) ought to be saved in MSG format.

The majority of users' emails are sent as HTML making my algorithm roughly as follows:

```
1. If email has attachment(s), save as MSG and be done
2. If email is stored as text, save as text and be done
3. If email is not stored as HTML store as MSG and be done
4. Decide if the HTML should be converted to text and
     store it as text if so
     store it as MSG if not
```

This is straightforward with exception of Step #4: How can I decide which format an HTML-formatted email should be converted to upon saving?

Comment: Why bother? Storage is so cheap, and you run the risk of your algorithm making the wrong decision. Maybe zip the msgs instead?

Comment: It's network storage that many users feed into and about a hundred emails per day per user with a requirement of many years for retention. Using an archiving tool creates complications for end users who aren't computer savvy and I can't control the front end for opening the documents.

Comment: Another consideration I've made is wrapping documents in a semi-transparent format that decompresses and opens automatically. That way it's mostly transparent, at least for viewing. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything available for this purpose. (Closest thing I need is an executable packer -- but those seem to be very specific to executables.)

Answer (score 2):

An idea: count the weighted density of HTML tags in the message. Choose a threshold based on existing data. Messages with HTML density higher than the threshold get stored as MSG; messages with density lower than the threshold get stored as plain text.

How do you calculate the weighted density? Use an HTML parsing library. Have it parse the document and count the number of each type of HTML tag are in the document. That's all you need from the library. Multiply each tag-count by its weight and sum them together. Then try converting the message to plain text and counting the number of characters in the message. Divide the weighted-tag-count-sum by that number and you have your density.

What should the density be weighted by? By a table you create with the importance of each type of HTML tag. I would guess that losing bold and italics are not too bad. Losing ordered and unordered lists lists are a bit worse, unless bullets and numbers are preserved when the messages are are converted to plain text. Tables should be weighted highly as they are important to the formatting. Choose a weight for unrecognized tags too.

How should you choose your threshold? Run your density-calculating function on a sample of emails. Also manually inspect those emails to see if they would be better off as MSG or plain text, and write that choice down for each email. Use some algorithm with that data to find the boundary value. I think that algorithm could be [Naive Bayes classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), but there might be a simpler algorithm in this case. Or a human-calculated guess might be good enough. I think you could make a guess after looking at a scatter plot of human-chosen format vs weighted HTML tag density, and eyeballing the density value that approximately separates the two format decisions.